# How do you filter a productCollection by multiple tags in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have an array of product tags, and I would like to find all products that are assigned these tags (I.E. return all products that have the tags "large" and "red"). I am currently using the following, but it does not work as expected.

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->setActiveFilter();

foreach ($tags as $tagName) {
    $tagId = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($tagName)->getId();
    $this->_productCollection->addTagFilter($tagId);
}
```

It seems that `addTagFilter()` only works once, not for multiple tags. I have also tried

```
$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->Where('relation.tag_id=?', $tagId);
```

but again, adding multiple `Where(relation.tag_id=?, $tagId)` does not appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this very interesting issue, when i was trying to filter product collection with value from Multi Select Attribute created, as it didn’t work as easy as it works for any other attribute, i.e.,

```
$product_collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code',"some value")
```

The collection filters provides a filter condition ‘finset‘, which helps us to filter attribute values inside a set.

First, we need to fetch the IDs for attribute’s various values, as follows:

```
$attributeOptionArray=array();
$opts_attr = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code');
foreach ( $opts_attr->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option){
$attributeOptionArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
```

Next we need to use this array of attribute values to filter across the product option:

```
$product_collection=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$product_collection->addAttributeToFilter("attribute_code",array('finset'=>array_search("Some Option's label",$attributeOptionArray)));
```

Explanation:

1. First, we load the product collection to a variable
2. We add “attributeToFilter“, in order to specify the filtering conditions.
3. With the array_search condition, we try to find the id corresponding to Option’s label.
4. Pass this id to filter with finset condition.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect all tag ids in an array then

```
$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->where('relation.tag_id IN (?)', implode(',',$tagId);
```

Comment: This works, but not exactly as I need. For example, if I wanted to get products that have "red" and "large" tags assigned, I may get a product with only the "red" tag, but not "large." I only want products that have both.

Comment: Yes this is an 'OR' request, to make it use an 'AND' you'll need something much more complicated, I'll investigate

Comment: You can try to get ALL product with the first tag, then ALL product with the other one (with the first request you tried) and then compare collections to get product that are in both collections

Comment: is the solution to get ALL products with tag1, ALL products with tag2 and then isolate the products in both?

Comment: You can use the "array_intersect" function to get products that are in both results. $array1 = getproduct with tag1, $array2 = get product with tag2, $array3 = array_intersect($array1,$array2);

Answer (score 0):

$prodids =array();//array of product ids
$tagName = array("Awesomeee","Black");//your tag name

```
                        foreach ($tagName as $_tagname) {
                            $tagId=Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($_tagname)->getId();
                            $collections = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                                ->addTagFilter($tagId);
                            $productIDs = $collections->getData();

                            foreach($productIDs as $_product){
                                array_push($prodids,$_product['product_id']);
                            }
                        }


                        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $prodids));
```

$_productCollection=$collection;//final product collection